# AlamoFire POST will get 'GET not allowed' error form DRF server

Tags: ios, django, django-rest-framework, alamofire, swift4

Used techs

- Django 2 with Django Rest Framework (Drf)
- JWT for authentication
- iOS/Swift4/Alamofire

here the issue.
django will recieve Alamofire's `POST` request as `GET` request.

iOS/swift4 code.

```
static func getToken (){
    let username = "root"
    let password = "DAMnShEIsSoHo1!t"

    let parameters: [String: Any] = [
        "username" : username,
        "password" : password,
    ]
    let url = ApiController.baseServerUrl + "api-token-auth"
    print("URL :: \(url)")
    Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
        .responseJSON { response in
            print("RESPONSE :: \(response)")
    }

}
```

log from iOS

> RESPONSE :: SUCCESS: {
>       detail = "Method \"GET\" not allowed."; }

log from django server

> my.ip.address - - [04/Mar/2018:07:55:32 +0000] "GET /api-token-auth/ HTTP/1.1" 405 40 "-" "Foodle/0.0.1 (com.domain.Appname; build:2;
>   iOS 11.2.0) Alamofire/4.6.0"

[image: DRF web console]

[image]

[image]

what shall i do from here?

ps. it works fine on PostMan, DRF web console and CURL

Answer (score 3):

ALWAYS add `/` at the end of your endpoint.

Comment: Thank you, You are my HERO.. THank you so much